# how can I modify the screen resolution of Ubuntu 21.04 non LTS stable version?

Tags: screen, display-resolution, configuration

I recently upgrade to Ubuntu 21, but something wrong happend, because now the desk does not have the optimal screen resolution, I mean, the desk only use a small region of the whole region, then I have a black rectangle around of the desk.

I try to change the resolution  using the Configuration menu, but there is not any option to change, as you can see in  the image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSyyJ.png)

I try to use

```
sudo xrandr
```

it return

xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
1024x768      76.00*

I try to know the graphics card using

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

it return
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 730] (rev a1)

How can I could to get a higher resolution of my screen in order to remove the black rectangle.

I am not using Virtualbox o something like this. I am using the standar version as you see in the next screen of my system
[image]

thank you in advange for you help

Comment: I know, it is no LTS version. Ubuntu 21.04. Other opticion is downgrade to a TLS stable version

Comment: I already correct the Question.

Comment: You should provide information regarding your hardware and in particular the GPU. And just to be sure, this is on bare metal not on virtualbox or the like?

Comment: I insert a screenshot in the botom of the question , and, no, i am not using virtualbox.

Comment: Please tell us about the graphics card (brand name and model).

Comment: *points at "Monitores"* Pretty sure you'd configure it in there, does it not give you options to change your resolution?

Comment: I try to know the graphics card using this comand  "lspci | grep VGA"  it return 
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 730] (rev a1).

Comment: and there is not option at "Monitores" as you can see in the figure attach.

Comment: You may need a proprietary nvidia driver for your graphics card. See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)